# Why am I getting U in the waveform for F1?

Tags: vhdl

I am getting U in the waveform instead of proper output.I don;t understand the reason it is happening in such a way. Can anyone please correct my mistake. Providing the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity circuit1 is port (
                           A, B: in std_logic;
                           F1 : out std_logic);
 end circuit1;

architecture structural of circuit1 is
signal A_B, B_A: std_logic;--internal signal declarations for A_B and B_A

component and_1 is port (--Component declaration for and_1
i1, i2: in std_logic;
o1: out std_logic);
end component;

component nor_1 is port (--Component declaration for nor_1
i1, i2: in std_logic;
o1: out std_logic);
end component;
begin
--Component placement and connections (formally called component instantiations)
C1: and_1 port map (i1 => A, i2 => B, o1 => A_B);
C2: and_1 port map (i1 => B, i2 => A, o1 => B_A);
C3: nor_1 port map (i1 => A_B, i2 => B_A, o1 => F1);
end structural;
```

Here is my Test bench code. I have tried to assign different values to A and B , and want the simulation to give the output accordingly.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity circuit1_tb is
end;

architecture bench of circuit1_tb is

  component circuit1 port (
  A, B: in std_logic;
  F1 : out std_logic);
  end component;

  signal A, B: std_logic;
  signal F1: std_logic;

begin

  uut: circuit1 port map ( A  => A,
                           B  => B,
                           F1 => F1 );

  stimulus: process
  begin
  
    -- Put initialisation code here
A<='1';
B<='1';
F1<='1';

    -- Put test bench stimulus code here
A<='0';
B<='0';
wait for 100 ns;

A<='0';
B<='1';
wait for 100 ns;

A<='1';
B<='0';
wait for 100 ns;

A<='1';
B<='1';
wait for 100 ns;

    wait;
  end process;


end;
```

Waveform:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMR7w.png)

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Entities and architectures for and_1, nor_1 are not provided here. Without them you would see C1, C2 and C3 unbound and F1 having the value of the driver in the testbench. Remove the testbench F1 assignment. Your 'initialisation code' doesn't, without a wait statement separating it from the following assignments. The value of F1 is the resolution of the drivers on the net. If you're seeing 'U' s the and_1 instances may be unbound (A signal defaults to 'U', A_B 'U' nor  B_A 'U' is 'U' to port F1, Testbench F1 '1' and port F1 'U' resolves to 'U', without C3 be no driver).

Comment: With entities and architectures for and_1 and nor_1 that are bound ( and match the component declarations) the solution is to [remove the assignment to F1 in the testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT8Kh.png).

Comment: Thank you user1155120 so much for replying. I am a new learner and I will keep in mind the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Are there any messages in the console about unbound components `and1` or `nor1`? Have you written these components yet? You can also add the internal signals in circuit1 to the waveform window and see which bits of circuit1 work.